# Create a list of video in PHP using query string?

Tags: php

I want to create a list of YouTube video like tutorial.
But I don't want to create every single page for every video, I see many website do this by using Query String but I don't know how to use it could anybody show me an example.

```
    ===index.php===

<html>
<body

<a href="tutorial.php?id=10">First tutorial</a>
<a href="tutorial.php?id=11">Second tutorial</a>
<a href="tutorial.php?id=12">Third tutorial</a>

</body
</html>


   ===tutorial.php===
<?php

$id = $_GET['1'];

**//So how do I display a page and video here?
//How would it determine where is id=10, id=11, id=12.....** 

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're asking us how to build a page you're not asking the right question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to pass a actual video id from your index page something like,

```
<a href="tutorial.php?id=OzHvVoUGTOM">First tutorial</a>
```

Than you can directly use `id` into the YouTube url,

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$videoLink = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

//you should validate the $id to ensure it corresponds to a video that exists

echo ' ?>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video<?php echo $id; ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video<?php echo $id; ?>.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<?php '; ?>
```

The video filename is something like `video1.mp4` with the number being the id of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter functions for that; it also makes sure that the provided `id` is an integer value:

```
if (($id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)) !== null) {
    // do stuff with $id
}
```

See also: [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/filter_input)

Answer (score 0):

variable `$_GET` is an array that contain key and value that you've passed via URL, exmple:

```
tutorial.php?id=12
tutorial.php?another_id=13
```

you can grab 12 by

```
$_GET['id']
```

and 13 by

```
$_GET['another_id']
```

look: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php